# connection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I get this error when connection to my database from codebehind.

> 'connection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'
>
> connection.ServerVersion 10.50.2500

But using the `asp:SqlDataSource` controller with the same connectionstring works fine.

I am really frustrated - do anybody have a input!

I get the exception here:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ServiceDepartmentSqlConnection"].ConnectionString))
 {}
```

Here is an example of the configuration string which does not work:

```
<add name="ServiceDepartmentSqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=serverIp;Initial Catalog=UserName;User ID=UserId;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: We're not mind readers - what is the connection string it fails on?

Comment: Sorry @Bridge: Does this answer your question? <add name="ServiceDepartmentSqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=serverIp;Initial Catalog=UserName;User ID=UserId;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: I have edited that information into the question for you. That aside, it looks like a valid connection string to me.